# Apache flink multi-threading/parallel execution

Tags: java, apache-flink, stream-processing

The input stream consists of data in JSON array of objects format.
Each object has one field/key named **state** by which we need to separate the input stream, see below example

Object1 -> "State":"Active"

Object2 -> "State":"Idle"

Object3 -> "State":"Blocked"

Object4 -> "State":"Active"

We have to start processing/thread as soon as we receive a particular state, keep on getting the data if a new state is similar to the previous state let the previous thread handle it else start a new thread for a new state. Also, it is required to run each thread for finite time and all the threads should run in parallel.

Please suggest how can I do it in Apache Flink. Pseudo codes and links would be helpful.

Comment: Is your processing logic different as per state? And is the value of 'State' only limited to one of the mentioned 4 or there can be multiple states dynamically?

Comment: @narush Processing logic is same and the states are finite for now but the number can increase in future.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Flink's Datastream API. Each JSON object can be treated as a tuple, which can be processed with any of the [Flink Operators](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/).

```
               /----- * *  | Active
------ (KeyBy) ------ *    | Idle
               \----- *    | Blocked
```

Now, you can split the single data stream into multiple streams using the KeyBy operator. This operator splits and clubs together, all the tuples with a particular key (State in your case) into a keyedstream which is processed in parallel. Internally, this is implemented with hash partitioning.

Any new keys(States) are dynamically handled as new keyedstreams are created for them.

Explore the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/api_concepts.html#specifying-keys) for implementation purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer narush.. Can you please tell me how we can keep on getting input and execute each thread/key for finite time like 10 minutes. I am a newbie to flink and just know its basic.

Comment: You would anyways keep on getting input into that particular keyedstream until you have JSON objects coming in. If you want to perform some operations after a particular time, Flink's windowing comes into the picture. Please explore more by reading the well maintained [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I believe you'd need to first have an operator with a parallelism of 1, that "chunks" events by the state, and adds a "chunk id" to the output record. Whenever you get an event with a new state, you'd increment the chunk id.

Then key by the chunk id, which will parallelize downstream processing. Add a custom function which is keyed by the chunk id, and has a window duration of 10 minutes. This is where the bulk of your data processing will occur.

And as @narush noted above, you should read through the documentation that he linked to, so you understand how windows work in Flink.